# Looking for a word describing I suddenly understood a problem

Tags: word-request

I’m trying to think of a word to describe how I suddenly understood a problem after someone explained it to me.

Comment: Off the top of my head, **dawned on me** is what I would recommend: https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/dawn-on I'd be great if you could provide an example sentence with a series of blanks showing how you intend to use the word you're looking for.

Comment: It's claimed that Archimedes shouted, "Eureka!"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One word you can use is **enlightened**.

> give (someone) greater knowledge and understanding about a subject or situation.
>
> <sup>*(from Google)*</sup>

Example: Jane was **enlightened** after watching the videos on the Internet regarding chemical bonding.

There's also [a badge of this name](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/badges/19/enlightened) on the site.

Comment: Enlightenment does not come suddenly.

Answer (score 2):

The first word that comes to mind is, Eureka!

Comment: In AmE we often say, *She had a **eureka** moment,* meaning that the answer suddenly came to her.

Answer (score -1):

Suddenly, **the penny dropped**. I now understood...

Suddenly, everything about this problem **fell into place**. I now understood...

Suddenly **i caught on**, the explanation had helped me to understand...

Suddenly **i came to realize** that...

Suddenly **i latched on**. The solution was...

- All of the above examples will work without 'suddenly' too, as they have a degree of suddenness in the phrase itself, but it gives them extra suddenness :-)

Then **it dawned on me** ...

- This one is rather slow, and the addition of 'suddenly' will only confuse the issue, but it is still applicable if you took a few minutes to fully realize the problem/solution